# Apply multiple conditional classes in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I used style binding in Vue in this way:

```
v-bind:style="{'width': + width + 'px', 'left': + x + 'px', 'top': y + 'px'}"
```

When I required to bind multiple conditional classes, I used below syntax but it won't work!

```
v-bind:class="{(position)?position:'', (direction)?direction:''}"
```

Is there other way to apply multiple classes? Single class(without {}) works.

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kunjsharma/o0kL7myt/

Comment: Try this: `:class="{ position, direction }"`, or `v-bind:class="[(position)?position:'', (direction)?direction:'']"` *(`[]` instead of `{}`)*

Comment: When I google "vue class binding" I get [this page](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) from the official docs as the top result, which easily answers your question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The class binding expression in your template is invalid JavaScript syntax.

Did you mean to bind an array like this:

```
:class="[position, direction]"
```

So if `position` is `'right'` and `direction` is `'rtl'` then the element will have the classes `right` and `rtl` applied to it.

Binding an object is usually used when you have static class names that you want to apply conditionally based on some condition. Looking at your code, it doesn't seem like this is what you want to do.

For example, if you want to conditionally apply the static classes `pressed` and `active` based on some conditions, you can do this:

```
:class="{ pressed: pressedElement === el, active: !hidden }"
```

If `pressedElement === el` is true then the element will get the `pressed` class applied to it, likewise for `active` (I just made up some arbitrary expressions).

Answer (score 15):

There are 2 syntaxes you can use:

- Object: `:class="{ position, direction }"`
- Array: `:class="[position ? 'position' : '', direction ? 'direction' : '']"`

You can also make `:class` a string, but that's messy when you want to use conditionals for multiple classes. You could also do a [computed property](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/vue/computed):

```js
computed: {
  myClass: function() {
    return [position ? 'position' : '', direction ? 'direction' : ''].filter(c => !!c).join('');
  }
}
```

See [Conditional Classes in Vue](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/vue/conditional-class) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for answering, much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The object based syntax for class definition is:

```js
{
    className: isEnabled,
    anotherName: isOtherEnabled,
}
```

where the key (`className`) is the name of the class and the value (`isEnabled`) is whether it is enabled or not.

So in your case you might need `{ position: position, direction: direction }`. You could even let javascript infer the key names for you `{ position, direction }`.

If you instead want to set the class-name to be the value of the position and direction properties then you should instead use the array syntax: `[position, direction]`. You can also achieve this with the class syntax like so: `{ [position]: true, [direction]: true }`

Comment: Thanks @James. Altering {} to [] makes the difference.