# Is it possible to set multiple classes with ternary expressions?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a popBox for adding data and when I click the button a window opens in which I enter data while the background is a little bit obscured with opacity.

```html
<div :class="[!popBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60']">
```

This code works perfectly, but I want also to be able to delete data with another popup box saying "do you want delete data" with two buttons.

My question is how can I merge the two below class bindings?

```html
<div :class="[!popBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60']">
<div :class="[!popDeleteBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60']">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply multiple conditional classes in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627099/apply-multiple-conditional-classes-in-vue-js)

Comment: Just put comma between `:class="[!popBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60', !popDeleteBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60']"`

Comment: Dario Marjanovic, if the answers helped, you should accept one, if not add more details to explain what's still not working

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update it to

```html
<p :class="[!popBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60', !popDeleteBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60']"></p>
```

You could use [class bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), with `v-bind:class`

```html
<p v-bind:class="{ 'opacity-60': popBox || popDeleteBox, 'opacity-100': !popBox && !popDeleteBox, }"></p>
```

Or, just as a string

```html
<p :class="`${!popBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60'} ${!popDeleteBox ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-60'}`"></p>
```

Comment: Glad you got it working :) You should accept the answer too

Comment: `:class` and `v-bind:class` are the same thing.